# CSS Scope & JQuery DatePicker

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm doing something wrong as my CSS wont apply.
I've Created a scope called DatePickerCss 
Which looks something like

```
DatePickerCss .ui-widget{font-family:Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:1.1em}DatePickerCss .ui-widget .ui-widget{font-size:1em}DatePickerCss .ui-widget input,DatePickerCss
....
```

Added the CSS to the page

```
<link href="~/Content/css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Then done the following, which im guessing is wrong?

```
<div id="DatePickerCss">
 <div id="datepicker"></div>
</div>
```

Then when I look no CSS is applied?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `#DatePickerCss` in the CSS file?

Comment: Jquery theme roller created as DatePickerCss